# iTerm/OSX Terminal: Change text margin from edge of window

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

Currently, I use iTerm on OS X. My terminal looks something along these lines:

[image: My terminal]

I came across this picture of a terminal setup on GitHub, and I wanted to imitate it:

[image: Target terminal]

Specifically, I wanted to change the padding/margin along the left side/bottom side of the window. While the picture in question appears to utilize OSX's default Terminal, I'm hoping it can be done in iTerm as well, although an OSX Terminal-specific solution would work too.

I've tried looking through iTerm and OSX Terminal's preferences (especially under the "Window" section on iTerm, but I have looked elsewhere), and I have yet to find an option for adjusting where the characters start along the left side.

I've also tried to implement this programmatically in Bash:

`bash -l | sed 's/^/   /'`

This seems to work fairly well, although it only indents program output, not my prompt line (and I'm having trouble setting such a piped command as my login shell).

Also, it only adjusts `stdout`, not `stderr` and piping it with `bash -l 2>&1` simply hides all of Bash's output altogether.

Have I just overlooked some setting in iTerm/OSX Terminal? Is there any other way to set an "inner text area" within the Terminal window (i.e. set padding along the sides)?

Comment: Well, for your prompt you could always try adding `export PS1="  $PS1"`  (give or take a space) to ~/.profile

Comment: Yes, I figured that would work out pretty easily, but there's no good way to indent the rest of the output, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone comes up at this question, this functionality is available via this plugin for iTerm2:

https://github.com/jaredculp/iterm2-borderless-padding

And from iTerm 3.1 on (currently in alpha), you can have it as an advanced option in `height of top and bottom margins` and `width of left and right margins`.

Comment: This answer would be improved by describing the location of these preferences.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like an option, although involves some compile& build hassle
http://hackr.it/articles/prettier-gutter-in-iterm-2/

i.e., you have to clone https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2.git and then patch
`sources/PTYTextView.h`

```
33c33
< #define MARGIN  5
---
> #define MARGIN  15
36c36
< #define VMARGIN 2
---
> #define VMARGIN 12
```

and then `make` it.

Comment: Still easier changing two variables than meddling around with a bunch of messy pile of shell script. Thanks!

Comment: Still works for me. Only caveat is that in the current beta builds, the "cursor guide" (persistent line highlight) doesn't go full-bleed. https://cloudup.com/cD9Leds1Wof

Comment: Those defines now reside in `iTermTextDrawingHelper.h`

Comment: Just to provide an update, these defines no longer work. You can find margin settings in the Advanced section of the preferences.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still with this issue like I was.
On iterm:

- Go to settings.
- Click on Appearance tab

Play around with Side Margings and Top & Bottom Margins

[image: screenshot]